# Test if two binary search trees has the same set of elements?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am just starting out with java and recursive methods and i need some help:
I need to determine if two Binary Search Trees has exactly the same set of elements, regardless of the structure of the tree.

I have written a method that checks if the the tree contains an element and its called contains()

this is what i got so far:

```
    public boolean sameContents(Node n2) {

    if (contains(n2, n2.key) && n2.left == null && n2.right == null) { return true; }
    if (contains(n2, n2.key) && n2.left != null) { sameContents(n2.left); }
    if (contains(n2, n2.key) && n2.right != null) { sameContents(n2.right); }
     return false; 
   }
```

Basicly my idea is that the method is running as long as a node still has a child, and if the trees match.
I call the method with for example testTree1.sameContents(testTree2); but the method always returns false... 
Can someone point out how this should be done?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) object - if two binary search trees contain the same elements then their iterators' `next` methods should return the same values (even if their structures are different).

```
// returns true if the trees are equivalent, else false
Iterator itr1 = tree1.getIterator();
Iterator itr2 = tree2.getIterator();
while(itr1.hasNext() && itr2.hasNext()) {
    if(!itr1.next().equals(itr2.next())) {
        return false;
    }
}
return !itr1.hasNext() && !itr2.hasNext(); // returns true if trees were the same size, else false
```

You ought to already have an inorder binary tree traversal method, so you've already got an Iterator - just add an ArrayList/Stack to take the place of the call stack so that you can pause the traversal (whenever you would be making a recursive method call, store the current node to your Stack)

Comment: Maybe provide some hints as how to go about writing this iterator.

Comment: Good idea, I've added an implementation hint

Comment: This will only work if the iterators return the elements in the same order. It might be better to use `equals` instead of primitive comparators if your iterator contains Objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do that. You can convert your trees into string representations, using pre-order traversal or in-order traversal. It will take `O(n)` time. Than you can check whether these strings equal or not. It can be done in `O(n)` time too. So, the total running time is `O(n)`.

This method looks similar to the solution with iterators but this one is more generic, since can be used for 'is-subtree' task (chechs wether tree `t1` is subtree of `t2`). In this case use can use `isSubstring()` method instead of `equals()`. If tree `t1` is subtree of `t2` than  `t1`'s string representaion is substring of `t2`'s. The `isSubstring()` can be done in `O(log n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a inorder traversal on both trees and check if the result of both the traversals are same. If same, could we assume that both trees have the same set of elements.